# RadGrid doesn't update data during paging

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, custompaging

I am using a Telerik RadGrid, and we're trying to get it to work with CustomPaging.  I feel like I'm close, but it's not updating the data on the web client.

My aspx page code looks like this:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>

<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel2" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgItemCustomFields" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="rgItemCustomFields_NeedDataSource" AllowPaging="true" AllowCustomPaging="true" VirtualItemCount="1000" >
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" Position="TopAndBottom"></PagerStyle>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

and my codebehind looks like this:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        rgItemCustomFields.Rebind();
    }
}

protected void rgItemCustomFields_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    int currentPage = rgItemCustomFields.CurrentPageIndex;
    DataTable data = GetData(currentPage);

    rgItemCustomFields.DataSource = data;
}
```

The page displays on the screen, and I see the first 10 rows of data, and I'm on page 1.  If I then click on a different page number, the grid disappears, preparing to display the new data, and the rgItemCustomFields_NeedDataSource method is called.

When I add a breakpoint and view the data in the rgItemCustomFields_NeedDataSource method it looks right: I see 10 rows, and they're different than what I have displayed on the screen.

I press continue in VS, the grid is redisplayed in the browser, but I'm back on page 1, and the original data is back.

Caching somehow? (I don't see how, but *something* is wrong.)  Am I doing something silly?

(I know that VirtualItemCount is wrong: it's just hardcoded to 1000 right now while I try to get the rest of the stuff working.  Also, once I allow different numbers of rows per page, the code will have to change; again, this is just simplified code while I try to get things working.  I don't *think* that these things are part of the problem, but feel free to correct me if I'm being an idiot.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the logic from this demo http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/paging/custom-paging/defaultcs.aspx